# writing sql without using aggregation

Tags: sql, aggregation

I was trying out some exercises of db-class.org videos.There was one problem of finding

> 'minimum gpa of all students who applied to colleges and have selected
>   CS as major'

Using aggregation this is;

```
select min(gpa) from student,apply where student.sid=apply.sid and major='CS';
```

result will be

```
min 
-----
 3.4
(1 row)
```

sid,gpa are of table Student whereas Apply table has fields sid,major

How can I rewrite this without using aggregation?

I tried

```
select gpa from student,apply  where major='CS' and   gpa < all(select gpa from student,apply where student.sid=apply.sid and major='CS');
```

But this gives me some 14 rows instead of the correct result
gpa

```
-----
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
 2.9
(14 rows)
```

Why does this happen?can someone please help me?

Comment: I would use an explicit inner join as opposed to that implicit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to reuse your query, I think you're missing a join on student and apply on the outer query. Also I think you should use `<=` instead of `<`. Also note that knowing your DBMS would help.

```
select gpa from student, apply
where major='CS' and student.sid = apply.sid and gpa <= all (
    select gpa from student, apply
    where student.sid = apply.sid and major='CS'
)
```

Comment: You'll get a record and compare it against all the others (including itself!). That record can't be lower than itself so to get it will have to be equal to itself. Or maybe I'm too sleepy as its 4 AM :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 gpa 
from student, apply 
where student.sid = apply.sid and major='CS'
order by gpa;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select gpa from student,apply 
where student.sid=apply.sid and major='CS'
order by gpa limit 1
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with subquery?

Comment: No, 'limit' is for the whole query, not in sub queries.